# Angular4: *ngIf in not hiding element, instead creating duplicate elements in Internet explorer 11

Tags: angular, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, angular-ng-if, ngx-charts

I am facing issue using *ngIf to show different types of chart based on some flag.
Its working in chrome but in IE11. *ngIf contents are getting added to DOM when flag is true, not getting deleted if flag is false.

Because of this each time I toggle flag new chart are getting created.

please help me. if I am doing something wring.

Context:
We have two type of forms checkbox/radiobox. Once user clicks **submit** Button. Charts will rendered accordingly
Checkbox - bar chart
Radiobox - pie chart

contents are switched using ***ngIf**. its working in chrome.

**In IE11**,
**When *ngIf flag sets to false. element is not removed and replaced, instead creating new set of chart and forms.**

```html
<ht-check-form 
  *ngIf="!chartDisplay"
  [surveyDetails]="survey"
  (onFormSubmit)="submitSuvery($event)"
></ht-check-form>

<ht-chart
  *ngIf="chartDisplay"
  [surveyDetails]="survey"
  [chartResult] = "chartData"
></ht-chart>
```

Sample code is in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/bANp2nJzyVMTFpK9F8NE?p=preview

Comment: Help here is appreciated.

Comment: I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it happens.
But it also happened to me, with the same kind of HTML markup: an element with `*ngIf="condition"` followed by another element with `*ngIf="!condition"`.

Sometimes (~1% of the times), one of those elements would be duplicated. When leaving/coming back to the page, it was ok again. Seems like a weird, random, bug.

Instead, I used a `ngSwitch`.

In your case, it would look like this:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="chartDisplay == null">
    <ht-check-form 
      *ngSwitchCase="true"
      [surveyDetails]="survey"
      (onFormSubmit)="submitSuvery($event)"
    ></ht-check-form>
    <ht-chart
      *ngSwitchCase="false"
      [surveyDetails]="survey"
      [chartResult] = "chartData"
    ></ht-chart>
</ng-container>
```

let's be clear: it's supposed to be exactly the same thing! (just maybe better in performance because there's only one "watcher")

but so far, it has worked for me; I don't have that weird duplication anymore

Comment: even after using switch case, it is creating duplicate elements.